# Почему form_teacher работает, а form_scholar - нет?

Tags: javascript, html

Задача: когда пользователь вводит неправильные данные, выводится алерт со значением неправильной формы. Проблема в том, что значения с полей `form_teacher` работают ок, а значения с полей `form_scholar` работают неправильно.

```
function validate() {

    var name_teacher = document.forms["form_teacher"]["name_teacher"].value;
    var surname_teacher = document.forms["form_teacher"]["surname_teacher"].value;
    //  и так дальше с form_teacher.
    var name_scholar = document.forms["form_scholar"]["name_scholar"].value;
    var surname_scholar = document.forms["form_scholar"]["surname_scholar"].value;
    //  и так дальше с form_scholar.
    var vse = new Array(name_teacher, surname_teacher, name_scholar, surname_scholar)
    for (var i = 0; i < vse.length; i++) {
         if (i != "") {
            if (/[а-яА-Я]/.test(i)) {

            }
            else {
                return false;
                alert(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код не должен работать ни с одним полем, т.к. здесь

```
if (/[а-яА-Я]/.test(i)
```

у вас проверяется число на буквеную регулярку, что естественно вернет false, ну и тут неправильно

```
(if (i != ""))
```

т.е. необходимо просто неменого переписать код - вместо

```
test(i)
```

написать

```
test(vse[i])
```

вместо

```
i != ""
```

написать

```
vse[i] != ""
```

Comment: вот так
var vse = new Array(name_teacher, surname_teacher, last_name_teacher, patronymic_teacher, patronymic_2_teacher, patronymic_3_teacher, name_scholar, surname_scholar, class_scholar)
    for (var i = 0; i < vse.length; i++) {
         if (vse[i] != "") {
            if (/[а-яА-Я]/.test(vse[i])) {

            }
            else {
                return true;
                alert(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Comment: Он все равно не работает)  Поля из `form_scholar`. 
Переводят на друг страницу, как будто все правильно, а они должны выводить алерт.

Comment: Проблема не в этом коде. Возможно, вы как-то не так вешаете обработчик...